# Equivalence of Tightness of Seqeuence of CDFs

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

In Durrett, a sequence of cdf $\{F_n\}$ is called tight if for all $\epsilon > 0$< there exists $M_\epsilon$ such that $\limsup 1-F_n(M_\epsilon)+F_n(-M_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon$.

In Rosenthal, a sequence of probability measure is called tight if for all $\epsilon$, there exists $a<b$ both finite such that $\mu_n([a,b]) \geq 1-\epsilon$ for all $n$.

[image]

[image]

Are these two definitions equivalent?

I can write $\limsup 1-F_n(M_\epsilon)+F_n(-M_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon$ as $\limsup F_n(-M_\epsilon)-F_n(M_\epsilon) \leq \epsilon-1$, which can be writen as $\liminf \mu_n(-M_\epsilon, M_\epsilon])=\liminf F_n(M_\epsilon)-F_n(-M_\epsilon) \geq 1-\epsilon$

From this, it's clear that the definition in Rosenthal implies the definition in Durrett.

However, the converse is not clear to me. Since we can have for all $n$, $\mu((-M_\epsilon, M_\epsilon]) < 1-\epsilon$ while $\liminf \mu((-M_\epsilon, M_\epsilon]) = 1-\epsilon$, in which case the definition in Rosenthal wouldn't hold.

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you take $a = -M_\epsilon-1$ and $b=M_\epsilon+1$?

Comment: Also, Durrett later defines tightness as $\lim\inf \mu_n([-M, M]) \geq 1-\varepsilon.$

Comment: @whuber does that matter? Since we can still have $\mu_n([a,b]) = \mu_n([a-1, b+1])$

Comment: @User1865345 is that one equivalent to one in Rosenthal? I don't see it.

Comment: Draw a picture.  The key idea concerns the distinction between $\Pr(X\lt x)$ and $\Pr(X\le x)$ when expressed in terms of the distribution function of $X.$  Slightly widening the interval overcomes that minor technical point, enabling you to see the sense in which $1-F_n(M_\epsilon) + F_n(-M_\epsilon)$ is essentially expressing the probability of the interval $[-M_\epsilon, M_\epsilon].$

Comment: @whuber but my problem is that even if $\liminf \mu_n([-M,M]) \geq 1-\epsilon$, we may have $\mu_n([-M,M]) < 1-\epsilon$. Does it suffice to get close enough to $1-\epsilon$?

Comment: Apply the assumption to $\epsilon/2$ and use that result to draw your conclusion about $\epsilon.$  This is where the "for all" quantification of $\epsilon$ is helpful.

Comment: @whuber got it thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Durrett's definition, choose $M$ so that for all $\liminf \mu_n([-M,M]) \geq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for a fixed $\epsilon > 0$.

Then eventually, $a_n = \inf_{m \geq n} \mu_m([-M,M]) \geq 1-\epsilon$ since $\liminf \mu_n([-M,M]) > 1-\epsilon$.

So eventually, $\mu_n([-M,M]) \geq 1-\epsilon$, and this suffices since finite collection of probability measures is tight.